# How to check if a string contains English letters (A-Z)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I check whether a string contains the English Letters (A through Z) in Objective-C?
In PHP, there is preg_match method for that.

Comment: *Contains* or *only contains*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One approach would be to use regular expressions — the [`NSRegularExpression`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. The following demonstrates how you could detect *any* English letters, but the pattern could be modified to match only if the entire string consists of such letters. Something like `^[a-zA-Z]*$`.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [[[NSRegularExpression alloc]
  initWithPattern:@"[a-zA-Z]" options:0 error:NULL] autorelease];

// Assuming you have some NSString `myString`.
NSUInteger matches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:myString options:0
  range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];

if (matches > 0) {
  // `myString` contains at least one English letter.
}
```

Alternatively, you could construct an [`NSCharacterSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCharacterSet) containing the characters you're interested in and use `NSString`'s [`rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) to find the first occurrence of any one. I should note that this method only finds the first such character in the string. Maybe not what you're after.

Finally, I feel like you could do something with encodings, but haven't given this much thought. Perhaps determine if the string could be represented using ASCII (using [`canBeConvertedToEncoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/canBeConvertedToEncoding:)) and then check for numbers/symbols?

Oh, and you could always iterate over the string and check each character! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use simple `NSPredicate` test.

```
NSString *str = @"APPLE";
NSString *regex = @"[A-Z]+"; 
NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex]; 
BOOL result = [test evaluateWithObject:str];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [NSCharacterSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and use the rangeOfCharacterFromSet: method to see if the returned NSRange is the entire range of the string.  [characterSetWithRange](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000157-characterSetWithRange_) would be a good place to start to create your characterSet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NSRegularExpression` Class (Apple's documentation on the class can be viewed [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html))